# Use environment variable in NuGet config?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

Is there a way to use an environment variable in `NuGet.Config` file?

Currently I am constrained to using relative path, as follows:

```xml
<configuration>
  <config>       
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\teampackages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

But would be really handy to have an environment variable with absolute path instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you run `nuget pack MyProject.csproj` on a project with a corresponding `MyProject.nuspec` file in the same directory, NuGet will make the MSBuild properties available as tokens in the format `$Property$`, where `Property` is the name of the MSBuild property.  For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2013</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="$OutputPath$MyProject.pdb" target="lib\net40"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

In this example `$id$`, `$version$`, `$title$`, `$author$` and `$description$` are special values provided by NuGet itself based on the project file and AssemblyVersion attribute (normally found in AssemblyInfo.cs).  However, `$OutputPath$` is an MSBuild property defined in the common targets.  You could also use $MSBuildProjectDirectory$ or any other standard property.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#replacement-tokens)

Comment: Oh, so that's what the `nuspec` file is for. Thanks! What about environment variable, like PATH for example?

Comment: They might work via MSBuild properties.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I am not sure I understand how it answers the question. When I use a nuget.config with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="$MSBuildProjectDirectory$" />
  </config>
</configuration>` it creates a folder called `$MSBuildProjectDirectory$` next to the .sln file instead of using the project directory. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: I've jused MSBuild properties successfully in .nuspec files, but not in nuget.config.  It may be that they are not supported in nuget.config.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the syntax:

```xml
<configuration>
  <config>       
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="%ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE%/teampackages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

**Important Notes**

1. The variable name should be surrounded with `%%`; for Example `%env_variable_name%`
2. Do **NOT** use `$env_variable_name` syntax. (for MAC and Linux compatibility reasons)
3. The directory separator is `/` and **NOT** `\` (for MAC compatibility reasons)
4. This requires NuGet 3.4+
5. For more info [here is the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#using-environment-variables)

Answer (score 3):

NuGet V3 supports a Global Packages Folder, see http://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html.

NuGet V3.2 supports a global NUGET_PACKAGES environment variable to specify the location of the shared global packages folder. See:
https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-3.2

Maybe one of these can help you solve your issues.

I had the same question as you did and these features look promising in solving the actual issues I had. NuGet 3.2 is only available for VS2015, and we have some other issues with 2015, so I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 2):

This works using standard %foo% environment variable references as of nuget 3.4 and higher:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1852